# Problem when installing Anki: unmet dependencies

Tags: installation, dependencies, anki

I'm trying to install Anki SRS http://ankisrs.net/ on (freshly-installed) Ubuntu 13.04, but it isn't going swiftly:

> ```
>  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  anki: Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
>  Depends: python-qt4 (>= 4.4) but 4.9.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
>  Depends: python-simplejson (>= 1.7.3) but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
> ```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what's happening is `dpkg package.deb` does not install dependencies automatically. You should be able to read that in your output (see example below.) So after running this line to install your `.deb` file

```
sudo dpkg -i anki-2.0.33.deb
```

You should run this line to install the unmet dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The `-f` option stands for 'fix,' so apt-get will go and download all the unmet dependencies (assuming they are in the apt-get package index.) For more on this, take a look at [this answer over on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/537371)

This was my output when running the files. Notice how in the second block, `apt-get` is installing the unmet dependencies, one of which is `python-sqlalchemy` as noted in the other answer. Afterwards, anki works fine.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i anki-2.0.33.deb
Selecting previously unselected package anki.
(Reading database ... 196396 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack anki-2.0.33.deb ...
Unpacking anki (2.0.33) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of anki:
 anki depends on mplayer | mplayer2; however:
  Package mplayer is not installed.
  Package mplayer2 is not installed.
 anki depends on lame; however:
  Package lame is not installed.
 anki depends on python-sqlalchemy; however:
  Package python-sqlalchemy is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package anki (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 anki
```

Notice how the missing dependencies are the ones being downloaded

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  esound-common lame libaacs0 libaudiofile1 libbluray1 libesd0 libgif4
  libpostproc52 libsdl1.2debian libsvga1 libvdpau1 mplayer python-sqlalchemy
  python-sqlalchemy-ext
Suggested packages:
  libbluray-bdj pulseaudio-esound-compat nvidia-vdpau-driver vdpau-driver
  mplayer-doc netselect fping python-sqlalchemy-doc python-psycopg2
  python-mysqldb python-kinterbasdb python-pymssql
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  esound-common lame libaacs0 libaudiofile1 libbluray1 libesd0 libgif4
  libpostproc52 libsdl1.2debian libsvga1 libvdpau1 mplayer python-sqlalchemy
  python-sqlalchemy-ext
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,729 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [Anki](https://anki.googlecode.com/files/anki-2.0.12.deb), and tried installing, and I got similar issues.  Here is what I did.

I just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sqlalchemy
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

You may have to do `sudo apt-get -f install`, before you install Anki.

[image]

Comment: What is `<file_name>`?

Comment: @FeloVilches is the name of the file downloaded.